# Spectrum of $\sigma^{-1/2}\rho\sigma^{-1/2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\rho$ and $\sigma$ be trace class operators.
Thus, they have eigenvalues and eigenvectors, and can be diagonalized just as finite dimensional matrices.

Now we consider $\sigma^{-1/2}\rho\sigma^{-1/2}$. Is this still have eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Of course, this one is not any more trace class (not even bounded !) 
But since this one has good operational meaning, i hope this one doesn't behave too badly.

Comment: Check my edit. This site uses `$`, not `\`` (I suppose you took that from SO).

Comment: To be diagonalizable you should assume at least normality, if you mean trace class operator on a separable Hilbert space. Furthermore, you assume that $\sigma$ is invertible ? You should be more clear about your assumptions.

Comment: A trace class operator need not be diagonalizable.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, they are all on separable Hilbert space. Also, \rho and \sigma are supposed to be self-adjoint (thus, of course normal)  in addition to being trace class. Also, \sigma is supposed to be invertible (otherwise exponent -1/2 doesn't make sense...)

Comment: What's an example of an invertible trace-class operator? In infinite dimension...

Comment: @Epsilon what do you mean when $\sigma$ is invertible?

Comment: (1) trace class -> self adjoint + trace class. I guess this is diagonalizable... since it is compact and self adjoint.

Comment: (2) "\sigma is invertible" means \sigma^-1 exists. I don't require \sigma^{-1} is bounded  nor its domain is dense. example of such sigma is just a diagonal matrix, whose diagonal entities are diag{1, r, r^2 ... , } (r<1). Then \sigma^{-1} is diag{1,1/r, 1/r^2,....}  I think its domain is not empty.